# Equivalent of "glpsol" in GLPK API

Tags: c++, linear-programming, glpk, mathprog

I was wondering if there is an equivalent in GLPK Api of the command line function "glpsol".

Because I have a model which is written in a .mod file and data in .dat file.
In command line I can solve it by calling this line :

```
glpsol --model flow-glpk.mod --data your_data_set.dat
```

I would like to solve the same problem in a C/C++ program without execute an "execv()" call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at mplsamp2.c in the examples directory of the [source distribution](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/), I believe it does what you want, you just have to change the hardcoded names appropriately to your application.

GLPK comes with a nice manual, *3.2 Routines for processing MathProg models* details how to deal with MathProg models using the C API.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for.
Does there is a way to catch the result ?

Comment: @Aleanar Glad to hear it helped. In the documentation, look at `glp_get_col_prim()` for example to retrieve the value of a variable at the solution, etc., these methods are documented in *2.7 Simplex method routines*.